# How to change the style of Android WebView link Highlight Border

Tags: android, webview

When I click a link in webview it will show an highlight orange border.
I want a thinner border or just an underline when I click a link.
How can I change the style of the border either by changing the code of webview or CSS file.
(-webkit-tap-highlight-color is not what I want for it just changes the color of the border)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android webview remove blue link border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138968/android-webview-remove-blue-link-border)