# Android webview remove blue link border

Tags: android, hyperlink, webview, border

When using webview in my application, everytime I click on a link a blue box highlights the text or image. Is there anyway of removing this feature from webview?

Answer (score 2):

For accessibility reasons you shouldn't just blanket set the tap highlight color to transparent.

For elements where you want full control:

1.) Remove the tap-highlight-color

```
.btn {
    ....

    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

2.) Add a new *:active* state (in this example set a background color

```
.btn:active {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1.0);
}
```

3.) On some elements like  you may see a blue or orange border, this is just to the focus state, to remove the border:

```
.btn {
    ....
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    outline: 0;
}
```

4.) Add a *:focus* state

```
.btn:focus {
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1.0);
}
```

5.) For bonus points add a *:focus:active* state

```
.btn:focus:active {
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't have 50 reputation to post a comment.
Blow is the main content from the link in above answer.

```
    * {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);  
    }
```

rgba() is just like rgb(), but it takes a 4th parameter for opacity.